# Что из себя представляет атрибут TargetedPatchingOptOut и где он применяется?

Tags: c#, .net

Что из себя представляет атрибут `TargetedPatchingOptOut` и в каких случаях он применяется?

На `MSDN` документацию по атрибуту не нашел, возможно плохо искал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот атрибут разрешает NGen инлайнить методы за пределы сборки.

В чем может быть проблема и почему методы между сборками не инлайнятся в ngen по умолчанию? Представим такую ситуацию:

1. Есть сборка A, которая вызывает метод M из сборки B.
2. NGen заинлайнил метод M в сборке A и сохранил бинарник в свой кеш.
3. Сборку B обновили - и реализация метода M изменилась.
4. Сборку A запускают... и вызывается старая версия метода M, в то время как в GACе давно уже новая версия сборки лежит.

Поэтому NGen, в отличие от JIT-компилятора, методы между сборками не инлайнит если это не разрешили делать явно.

---

Применяется этот атрибут при совпадении следующих условий:

1. предполагается использование NGen.exe;
2. метод доступен из других сборок (публичный или защищенный метод в публичном классе некоторой библиотеки);
3. метод достаточно короткий;
4. метод никогда не будет изменяться.

Если используется не ngen.exe, а обычный JIT-компилятор - то этот атрибут не нужен, ведь сборка не может измениться в процессе выполнения и проблемы устаревшего кешированого кода не существует.

Для недоступных снаружи методов атрибут также не нужен - внутренний метод заинлайнить не проблема.

С третьем условием также все должно быть понятно - крупные методы все равно не инлайнятся, и атрибут для них бесполезен.

Четвертое условие - самое ограничивающее. Обойти его можно, если очищать бинарники всех зависимых сборок при изменении библиотеки. Такое решение подходит для внутренних библиотек проекта (если проект всегда переустанавливать целиком - то и о проблеме кешированных устаревших методов можно не думать).